# Is it possible to design/write openstreetmap (osm) routeplanner?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I can display location on openstreetmap. I can calculate distance in between user location and the search result location based on their co-ordinates.

Now I like to make a routeplanner, like google does. Is there a way to write osm - openstreetmap routeplanner.

I would be highly thankful if some of you could kindly guide me on this

Comment: Do you need it to figure out what the best route is from a list of locations?  If so, it's not _really_ possible on a larger list of locations.  If you just need to write a front-end so someone can plan their own route or enter the route in explicitly, then that is definitely possible.  You should give more details as to what you are looking at doing.

Comment: Yes. For example: http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/

Comment: nathansnider is it that simple ? Tomorrow, I will try to integrate the code with my app and see.

Comment: Do you really want to write your own routing engine? Or do you want to use one of the many available [online routers for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use Leaflet for this task, check the [list of Leaflet plugins for route calculation](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#routing).

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for sharing this. I am using leaflet 0.7.3, could you please give me download link of leaflet routing machine ? compatible with 0.7.3 ? And where to place this downloaded files in my jsf project(structure). I am asking this because I was not able to find the download link. All I could find was this: https://github.com/StephanGeorg/leaflet-routeboxer and i do not know, what to do with this project and how this is going to work with my leaflet 0.7.3 version.

Comment: Ok, the download works. Do I just have to include the .js(javascript) files into existing leaflet folder(where the leaflet.js) and give namespace for routing js files into the viewpages ?